# Why Inheritance get fail in this bunch of code

Tags: swift, oop, generics, inheritance

I am working on Generic type classes when I write code like

```
class BaseResponseData<A: BaseAttributeData, I: BaseIncludeData<BaseAdminData>> {

}

class BaseAttributeData{

}

class BaseIncludeData<A: BaseAdminData> {

}

class BaseAdminData{

}

class ChildAdminData : BaseAdminData{

}
class profileResponse: BaseResponseData<BaseAttributeData, IncludeData> {

}

class IncludeData: BaseIncludeData<BaseAdminData> {

}
```

this code giving me an error 'BaseResponseData' requires that 'IncludeData' inherit from 'BaseIncludeData'

Comment: Just tried your code and it compiles on Xcode10.

Comment: So you just want to say its an Xcode error because it's not run on Xcode 9.4